# How to extract the promise contents in Net.httpRequestAsync?

Tags: voximplant

I am not good at JS, how can I extract the promise contents after executing Net.httpRequestAsync and put it into a variable?

I tried to use await but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function () { 
  let x = await Net.httpRequestAsync(...) 
  ...
}
```